# What function will survive evolution?

Tags: evolution, definitions

I wrote the following phrase in my scientific text:

*X is ubiquitous in life of Y. On some occasions X might be detrimental, resulting, for example, in so so phenomena. But is it plausible that a function that takes 50% of organism resources would have only negative effects? The answer is likely "no" because such a function would have likely not survived the evolution.*

But I was suggested that there a bug in my logic because if an adaptation is neutral and has no effect on reproductive fitness, it can be preserved. Would you agree with this critique? If so, how should I rephrase so that it become more correct?

Many thanks

Comment: `is it plausible that a function that takes 50% of organism resources would have only negative effects?` It sounds highly unlikely that an organism would invest half of its ressources into doing something that will reduce its own fitness (I should say "inclusive fitness" to be safer here). A mutation that would lead to such trait would be highly deleterious and should not raise in too high frequency in the population (unless eventually if the population size is really really small). That being said a recent and sudden environmental change could eventually lead to this type of 'maladaptation'.

Comment: `On some occasions X might be detrimental, resulting, for example, in so so phenomena.` Many traits can have environment dependent fitness effects and environmental heterogeneity can lead to strong variation in the trait's contribution to the individual fitness. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: "would have only _neutral and_ negative effects" would partly cover the critique, as it appears to me the argument hinges on the "50% of organism resources" which must have been previously firmly established.  It would be helpful to add language emphasizing that such an enormous drain on an organism cannot plausibly survive long in a species since that drain, itself, is a huge negative effect on individual fitness and hence on reproductive fitness.

Comment: Can you please let know whether my comment seem to answer your question. I am unsure I really understand your question and your feedback would help.

Comment: detrimental to what? Many adaptations are detrimental to an organisms but beneficial to their genes. Just look at social insects, or even your own somatic cells.

Comment: Detrimental for behavior. For example, sleep at night wastes our time. So, it should have some benefits.

Comment: Ia m sorry for the late reply (time zones differences). Thank you very much for the answers. So, the bottom line: do you think my phrase sounds?

Comment: @student a behavior cannot be detrimental to behavior, biologically speaking that makes no sense, it has to be detrimental to the organism, cells, or genes.